# Magento 1.5. After deleting product in admin section, category's products count doesn't decrease

Tags: magento, count, product

Is this a known bug ( can someone give a link )? How to fix it?

Comment: What have you tried? Are there any extensions installed? Did you rebuild the indexes from _System > Index Management_?

Comment: Nothing installed, "Did you rebuild the indexes from System > Index Management?" - Yes and clear all cache also

Comment: I have the same issue although I am using 1.4.2 After upload by CSV - product count almost doubled. I have cleaned cached - rebuild index - nothin

Answer (score 0):

What category count are you talking about? In layered navigation on the front end? In the category tree in the admin? Was it a simple or configurable product that you deleted? I assume you are on 1.5.1.0?

I don't see anything similar to this. You can search the Magento Bug Tracker here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I found the solution: 
Take a backup of your database first and then run this query

```
DELETE FROM catalog_category_product where product_id NOT IN (SELECT entity_id FROM (catalog_product_entity))
```